# Find minimum value in list<> using STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have list or vector of float numbers. How to find minimum value in list/vector using STL algorithm ? I can find with iteration, but is there more elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [std::min_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) algorithm. Note that it won't be any faster than your iteration based algorithm, it is still `O(n)` complexity. But the amount of code written will be less.

Comment: You beat me to the punch! Right answer though.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<float>::iterator iter = std::min_element(items.begin(), items.end());

std::cout << *iter << "\n";
```